Why does John 1:8 say that John was not the light when it was obvious that light already existed before John?
John 1 :7-8 Literal Standard Version
this one came for testimony, that he might testify about the Light, that all might believe through him; that one was not the Light, but—that he might testify about the Light.
If John is not the light, is it reasonable to think that the light mentioned in John 1 is different from the light in Genesis 1:3?

John the Baptist was NOT the light as John 1:8 correctly says.  Jesus was the light of the world as per John 1:4, 9 & 8:12.  This is a direct allusion to Ps 27:1 and Micah 7:8.

To close-voters.  If we close questions like this one, the site will become infinitely less interesting. Hermeneutics is not rocket science - because in rocket science there is only one good answer (most of the time). One of the things I like about this site is that we have created a culture where different interpretive approaches to questions can be discussed in an atmosphere of collegiality.

Some scholars believe that one of the purposes of the Gospel of John was to witness to followers of John the Baptist who thought his teaching was higher than that of Jesus. For example an introduction to this gospel published by the US Council of Catholic Bishops states:

The fourth gospel is not simply history; the narrative has been
organized and adapted to serve the evangelist’s theological purposes
as well. Among them are the opposition...
to John the Baptist’s followers, who tried to exalt their master at
Jesus’ expense.

Some of John's followers strongly believed that John's teaching ends in themselves rather than preparation for Jesus' ministry. Therefore the Gospel made it clear that John was not "the Light" but had come to bear witness to Jesus. Unlike in the synoptic gospels, Jesus does not submit himself to baptism in this account.  It is also in John's gospel alone that we find John specifically portraying himself as lower than Jesus. (John 3:29-31) This too fits with the idea that one of the purposes of this Gospel was to clarify John's subservient role.
This hypothesis is supported by the fact that the Mandaeans - contemporary followers of John the Baptist who claim him as their central ancient teacher - emphasize his role as a bringer light and consider Jesus to be an apostate follower of the the Baptist.

Mandaeans consider themselves followers of John the Baptist, and they
practice baptism as their central ritual. Baptism isn’t a one-time
conversion rite but something practiced repeatedly for the forgiveness
of sins and to connect with the world of light.

Second question: If John is not the light, is it reasonable to think that the light mentioned in John 1 is different from the light in Genesis 1:3?  I would say yes. Although John 1 intentionally parallels Genesis, John's "light" is a metaphor for eternal truth and the uncreated Word. In Genesis God creates light by speaking it into existence. But in John, Jesus IS the light; he IS the Word; and the Word IS God.  However, John does seem to connect his idea of "light" and "Word" with the Genesis idea that light is what began the process of creation.
Conclusion: John 1:8 clarifies that John was "not the light" in order to make sure that readers should look to Jesus - the Light of the World (John 8:12) - rather than seeking truth in the teachings and baptism of John.

Is the light mentioned in John 1 different from the light in Genesis 1:3?

I think John 1 intentionally parallels Genesis in that sense. It even starts with the same three words: "In the beginning." But of course, in Genesis, God "speaks" the light into existence, while in John, the Word (who is also the Light) "was" God.

Light was already present after Genesis 1:3, so it doesn't make sense that John 1:8 says that John is not the light. If John 1 is talking about a "spiritual" light and "John 1 parallels Genesis" why does it seem that John's testimony says nothing about the Genesis creation of this light. Is the light in Genesis 1:3 and the light in John 1 the same? Are they both spiritual light?

This is too complicated to resolve in comments. But it seems to me that Gen. is talking about physical light and John is talking about light as a metaphor for truth.

Alex Bailo ... I added a paragraph to my answer to deal with your question about light in Gen. and John 1.

Demonstrative Pronouns
John 1 (DLNT)

6 There came-to-be[d] a man, having been sent-forth from God. The name for him was John. 7 This one came for a testimony— in order that he might testify concerning the Light, in order that all might believe through him. 8 That one was not the Light, but came in order that he might testify concerning the Light— 9 the true[e] Light which gives-light-to[f] every person was coming into the world.

[d] Or, arose
[e] Light— the true Light. Or, Light. There was the true Light which, coming into the world, gives-light-to every person.
[f] Or, illuminates


The initial identification of the man begins with the pronoun αὐτὸς him and a name, John. The next statement uses a demonstrative pronoun οὗτος while adding the term μαρτυρίαν before reverting back to the initial αὐτοῦ. This one came as a witness that all might believe through him. Verse 8 uses yet another demonstrative pronoun ἐκεῖνος, that one...
Demonstrative pronouns give emphasis: οὗτος this one [that is, a man sent from God named John] came for a witness... ἐκεῖνος that one [that is, the one who might testify about the light in order that all might believe through him] was not the light.
Why State the Obvious?
Using ἐκεῖνος places emphasis on the fact the witness is not The-Light. This can be seen as necessary since the witness was to be universal: that all might believe through him. Historically, the witness fell short of all as only some believed him. Nevertheless, being sent from God means being equipped by God, which means the witness had the potential for universal success. Had the witness achieved universal success, it might lead one to mistakenly attribute the success to the witness. Hence, that one was not The-Light.
Another factor making it possible to blur the distinction between The-Light and the witness is the historical nature of a witness to an actual event. Verse 9 says the true light which gives-light-to every person was coming into the world which could also be understood as there was the true light which, coming into the word, gives-light-to every person. Regardless of when the witness was sent The-Light was subject to distinct events.

The coming of the Son of God in bodily form.
The crucifixion of the Son of God.
The resurrection of the crucified Son of God.
The return of the resurrected Son to the bosom of the Father.
The sending of the Parakletos, the Spirit of the Truth.

The complete witness necessarily comes after the True-Light is no longer present in the identical form as before the crucifixion. Thomas is an example. He would not believe the testimony of the disciples without seeing the wounds. With respect to The-Light, he rejected the witness until he saw The-Light, which for him was the wounded Jesus. Since the historical Thomas saw The-Light without His wounds, he could reject the disciples witness about The-Light until seeing the actual wounds, just as the other disciples had.
Those who never saw The-Light as Thomas are dependent on the witness to The-Light both without and with His wounds. Those who believe "see" as Thomas without seeing as Thomas. Unlike Thomas, they believe the witness. Yet, post-resurrection belief is through the witness but does not originate from the witness. Those who believe do so only because the The-Light returned to the Father which is evidenced by the presence of the Parakletos, the Spirit of the Truth in the witness and in the world.
This question recognizes the implication of present day activity of John's witness in the perfect tense ἀπεσταλμένος of the verb ἀποστέλλω. If the witness still has a present tense effect, it is possible to blur the distinction between believing the witness and believing The-Light. Therefore, John writes, that one was not The-Light.

@AlexBalilo I suppose that depends on whether one believes the witness has something to say about האור in Genesis 1:4.

If the true light in a person in John 1  , how does it compare to the light in Genesis 1:3?

Since the light in Genesis 1:3 already exists during John's time,  what reason would support that the light John 1, (a person) and the light in Genesis 1 :3 are the same?

@AlexBalilo If the Light of the World is from God, then I believe it existed from the beginning. Just because it is not revealed to man until later doesn't make it an afterthought for God. Also you need to consider John 1 is more closely related to Genesis 1:4 which speaks of both the Word, האור, that is The-Light and the darkness, then it does about Genesis 1:3 which is only about light. Any interpretation of John 1 which ignores Genesis 1:4 is flawed.

Light that brings about the day is what Genesis 1:4 show. The close relationship of John1 to the light that brings about the day in John 1 is not shown in your answer. Do you mean that the light that brings about the day in Genesis 1:4 is a person just like the light in John 1?

@AlexBalilo I mean you are attempting to denigrate the witness of the Light which is found in John by selectively interpreting Genesis 1. My answer addresses your question as to why it was necessary to state what some would see as obvious. But it is not obvious if you believe what John says and use it to understand Genesis. A mystery in the NT sense is an explanation of what was hidden. Therefore, John reveals what was hidden in Genesis 1. I understand you disagree. So I suggest dropping the issue or asking a new question.

Alleging that "I am attempting to denigrate" instead of addressing the issues that I brought up. I will stop commenting since what I have written can be read by anyone.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thank you for the invitation. I comment and don't chat.

Consider John 1:19-28.  There were people who considered John more than he was.


There is a difficulty about his saying, he was not the light. Conflicting with this is, “You were at one time darkness, but now you are light in the Lord” (Eph 5:8); and “You are the light of the world” (Mt 5:14). Therefore, John and the apostles and all good men are a light.
I answer that some say that John was not the light, because this belongs to God alone. But if “light” is taken without the article, then John and all holy men were made lights. The meaning is this: the Son of God is light by his very essence; but John and all the saints are light by participation. So, because John participated in the true light, it was fitting that he bear witness to the light; for fire is better exhibited by something afire than by anything else, and color by something colored.
--
Thomas Aquinas. (2010). Commentary on the Gospel of John: Chapters 1–21 (F. Larcher & J. A. Weisheipl, Trans.; Vol. 1, p. 52). The Catholic University of America Press.


